# Can a template member function specialization also be an instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm running into an issue with template specialization. The following builds and runs, but I'm not sure it should:

```
// template.h
template <typename T>
class interface{
public:
   void doSomething();
};

// template.cpp
#include "template.h"
#include <iostream>
template <> void interface<int>::doSomething(){std::cout << "Did something\n";}

// main.cpp
#include "template.h"
int main(){
   interface<int> instance;
   instance.doSomething();
   return 0;
 };

g++ main.cpp template.cpp; ./a.out
```

My understanding was that all compilation units were supposed to have access to all template specializations, which main.cpp does not. If I understand what's happening correctly, the specialization in template.cpp also instantiates interface< int >, so the symbol is generated and everything links happily. However, I'm pretty sure this falls into the realm of undefinedness and I can't count on this always working everywhere. Can someone please confirm or deny my suspicions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you didn't finish to type your title...

Comment: Well, first of all you are missing a `;` after the class definition/declaration.

Comment: Oops! I'm transcribing from my compiler machine to my internet machine and not doing very well.

Comment: It's explicit specialization, so it should be fine, right?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks -- I know that you can put the template implementation in a separate file as long as you explicitly instantiate, but I thought specializing outside of the view of a compilation unit that needs it was undefined (though now I can't find the section of the standard stating so.) I can't think of a situation where my code _wouldn't_ work, as the specialization and instantiation seem guaranteed to make the correct symbols, but I'm afraid a malicious compiler could refuse to build my code and still be compliant.

Comment: @Kevin I read in another question that it provides a complete definition so there's no issue.

Comment: You can work around your concern if you write an explicit specialization declaration in the header, e.g. `template<> class interface<int>;`. Good question, btw.

Comment: something soomething if a template specialization is not visible at the point of instantiation where that specialization applies something something undefined?

Comment: @jrok `template<> class interface<int>;` is a declaration of a class template specialization. In this case a class template member specialization is used, so the right code for its declaration is: `template <> void interface<int>::doSomething();`.

Comment: According to standard you should declare such explicit specializations before their first using. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061774/template-class-member-specialization-without-declaration-in-header) for details.